# Get Month Name of java.time.chrono.HijrahDate instance

Tags: java-8, hijri, umalquracalendar

```
HijrahDate hd=HijrahChronology.INSTANCE.date(LocalDate.of(2014,11, 25));
```

If we have `HijrahDate` Instance , it is expected to have a method in `UmalquraCalendar API` that shows the name of month :

i inspect properties of this instance using **groovy API** :

```
['era':AH, 
'class':class java.time.chrono.HijrahDate, 
'prolepticMonth':17233,
 'eraValue':1,
 'dayOfWeek':2,
 'leapYear':false, 
'chronology':Hijrah-umalqura, 
'dayOfYear':32]
```

However we  don't find the month name which must be one of the following list items :

> 1. Muḥarram (محرم meaning "forbidden"), so called because battle was
>      forbidden (haram) during this month. Muharram includes the Day of
>      Ashura.
> 2. Ṣafar (صفر meaning "void"), supposedly named thus because
>      pagan Arab houses were empty this time of year while their occupants
>      gathered food.
> 3. Rabīʿ I (Rabīʿ al-Awwal, ربيع الأوّل) meaning "the
>      first spring".
> 4. Rabīʿ II (Rabīʿ ath-Thānī ربيع الثاني or Rabīʿ al-Ākhir
>      ربيع الآخ
>
> .....................
>   ............ so on  [SEE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar#Months)

Thus , since there is no attribute save month's name , it is expwcted to have a method retrieve  this info ?

## What's this method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The date does not contain information about the names of the months or days. To get that you need a formatter:

```
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM").format(hd));
```

prints `Safar`.

Comment: what to do if we want to show __Safar 14-1444__

Comment: Change the pattern to get the format you need. See: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: appreciate your response. Above reference help me to do so __DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM-dd-yyyy").format(hidate)__

Answer (score 4):

Since the main language of `UmalQura` is the arabic langugage, Developers & programmers who uses  `UmalQuraCalender` want to display the month in arabic. Thus , we base on @assylias answer we can add the **Locale** object to print `صفر` instead of `Safar`

```
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM").format(hd,new Locale("ar")));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public String getIslamicDate(){
    return  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM",new Locale("ar")).format(HijrahDate.now());
}
```

I think this should work just fine and return the month in arabic language

Comment: but, this way date and year not comes in Arabic, is there any way ?