# Get Hijri date from future Gregorian date

Tags: java, calendar, hijri

How am I able to get hijradate from the code below but instead of now() I would like to get this from a future date.

```
java.time.chrono.HijrahDate hijradate = java.time.chrono.HijrahDate.now();
System.out.println("hijradate "+hijradate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s straightforward when you know how:

```
    LocalDate gregorianDate = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.FEBRUARY, 22);
    HijrahDate hijradate = HijrahDate.from(gregorianDate);
    System.out.println(hijradate);
```

This printed

```
Hijrah-umalqura AH 1440-06-17
```

If by Gregorian date you meant that you had your date in a `GregorianCalendar` object (typically from a legacy API that you cannot change or don’t want to change just now):

```
    GregorianCalendar gregCal = // ...

    ZonedDateTime gregorianDateTime = gregCal.toZonedDateTime();
    System.out.println(gregorianDateTime);
    HijrahDate hijradate = HijrahDate.from(gregorianDateTime);
    System.out.println(hijradate);
```

Output in one run on my computer was:

```
2019-02-22T00:00+03:00[Asia/Riyadh]
Hijrah-umalqura AH 1440-06-17
```

**EDIT:** For the sake of completeness here are my imports so you know exactly which classes I am using:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.chrono.HijrahDate;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
```

**EDIT:** To get the month: use your search engine. I used mine and found:

```
    int month = hijradate.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR);
    System.out.println(month);
    String formattedMonthName 
            = hijradate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM", new Locale("ar")));
    System.out.println(formattedMonthName);
```

This prints

```
6
جمادى الآخرة
```

The last lines are inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27141768/5772882).

Comment: i get errors running this error: cannot find symbol
                        LocalDate gregorianDate = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.FEBRUARY, 22);
  symbol:   method of(int,Month,int)
  location: class LocalDate

Comment: see also above: error: incompatible types: LocalDate cannot be converted to TemporalAccessor
                        HijrahDate hijradate1 = HijrahDate.from(gregorianDate);

Comment: I am using `import java.time.LocalDate;`. Have you by any chance got hold of a different `LocalDate` class?

Comment: thanks. how am i able to get the month of hijradate pls